# Python 3 - Django 1.9 persistent messages

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-1.9, django-messages

Is there some app which behaves the same as native Django messages framework, but can store messages/notifications permanently and to specific user (instead of storing them temporarily for the current session/user)? I searched over the Internet and I've found [django-persistent-messages](https://github.com/samluescher/django-persistent-messages) and [django-messages-extends](https://github.com/AliLozano/django-messages-extends) but none of them work - first because it's not updated ever since and therefore works only on Python 2, and the second [has bug when saving persistent message to the specific user](https://github.com/AliLozano/django-messages-extends/issues/18).
So, what are your recommendations? Do I have to write my own user notification system, or is there some better/easier way of achieving such thing?

Comment: Roll out your own, it works best, plus given that there is not lot of data that will go into, it will be best as per me.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the suggestion @RajeshYogeshwar!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [django/notifications for this](https://github.com/django-notifications/django-notifications). It has some helper methods to reduce the amount of work you need to have some features like marking them as read.

Another option is to create a model to hold your own notifications, it is not that complicated. Just replace every message with a model creation and you will have persistent messages. Adding features will take some time tho, so give django-notifications a check first.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it's too late now to use that because I already made my own implementation - and I don't regret it! :)